# Enumerating Ascii characters using range and enumerate

Tags: python

I'm new to this enumerate command and I'm not sure if I'm supposed to use it like this, what I want to do is to enumerate the ASCII characters from 0 - 129, and what I get is '1' before each character.

```
for x in range(129):
    xxx = chr(x)
    z = list(xxx)
    for i, a in enumerate(z, 1):
        print(i, a)
```

random text output:

```
1 .
1 /
1 0
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
1 6
1 7
1 8
1 9
```

Comment: looks like you don't need `enumerate`. Remove your inner `for` loop and just do `print(z)`

Comment: then i just get the chrs listed?

Comment: `for x in range(129): print(x, chr(x))`

Comment: @t.m.adam: they started the `enumerate()` value of at `1`, so you'd need `print(x + 1, chr(x))`

Comment: @MartijnPieters, true, but they also used `enumerate` on a single character. I think int, char makes more sense, but who knows..

Comment: @MartijnPieters, also, very detailed and well written answer, +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looping over a list with *a single character in it*:

```
>>> xxx = chr(65)
>>> xxx
'A'
>>> list(xxx)
['A']
>>> len(list(xxx))
1
```

You then loop over the `enumerate()` result for that *single character*, so yes, you only get `1`.

You repeat that inner loop for each value of `x`, so you do get it 129 times. It is your outer `for x in range(129)` loop that makes the `1`s repeat.

You'd use `enumerate()` for the *outer* loop, and there's no point in turning your single character into a list each time:

```
for i, x in enumerate(range(129)):
    xxx = chr(x)
    print(i, xxx)
```

Note that `x` is *already* an increasing integer number however. `enumerate()` is really just overkill here. Just print `x + 1` for the same number:

```
for x in range(129):
    xxx = chr(x)
    print(x + 1, xxx)
```